# How to disable automatically closing characters in SpringToolSuite4's Generic Text Editor

Tags: javascript, eclipse, visual-studio-code, spring-tool-suite

I use SpringToolSuite4 for my React.js project (on macOS). I write JS code there. I open the .js files in default "Generic Text Editor". It works pretty well - highlights my code, makes the suggestions. But one thing - I can't disable annoying auto-closing quotes.

I went to Preferences and disabled everything where I could find "insert automatically" or "close automatically" (Java - Editor - Typing, Web - Editor, and all other editors). It seems that Generic Text Editor completely ignored the settings and nothing changed. So does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: The JavaScript editing experience in the generic editor is provided by the same engine that runs in VSCode (as a language server), therefore I added the vscode-settings tab. If there is a way in VSCode to control this behavior, I would raise a bug against the Eclipse Wild Web Developer to see if they know how to make this work.